# Is it possible to change AlertDialog content to ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-dialogfragment

I have `DialogFragment` where in `onCreate` I create a simple `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                }
            })
            .create();
```

As you can see I'm not using any custom layout because I need just a simple dialog.
In `onClick` I want to make a call to the web-service and change dialog content to the `ProgressBar`. Is it possible to make this without using custom layout? To inflate a view with the `ProgressBar` programmatically and set it to the dialog?

Comment: there is no buttons on progressBar, so if you don't want to custom any layout, you must hide the alert and show the progressbar onClick event

Comment: You can't add a `View` to the default layout. You can only either inflate a view or you can programmatically create a layout that you can add to the dialog which in the end is basically the same as inflating from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use a progress dialog, is more simple

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
alertDialog.dismiss();
progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProgressDialouge](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) for your work.

A simple usage is

```
ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext);
progressdialog.setMessage("Processing...");
progressdialog.show();
```

When your work done call

```
progressdialog.dismiss();`
```